# Does selling a related option affect the holding period for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, options, hedging, long-term

Imagine the following scenario:

- I purchased 3 LEAP call options on XYZ in 2019 with a strike price of $200.00, expiring over a year from purchase in 2021.
- I also sold  3 call options on XYZ in 2019 with a strike price of $200.00, expiring one month prior to the LEAPs.

If I buy back the call options at a profit in 2019, can I still sell the LEAPs at a profit in 2020 (over 1 year from the purchase date) and report it as long term rather than short term capital gain in 2020?

Comment: Your title has the opposite sense of the question body.  Yes that scenario will affect the holding period, no you will not get long-term tax rates.